# Excel add-in for array function?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

Eventually I would like to be able to press a shortcut on the keyboard and excel run a user-defined array function, the emphasis being to perform not just on one cell but on a range of cells (i.e the 'array' in array function).

Would someone be able to tell me whether this is trivial and requires minimal development or how I would go about writing a add-in for it?

Thank you

ps this is for excel 2007

Comment: What do you mean, run a function? You want formulas created on the sheet?

Comment: This is a site for programmers. You will get a better answer if you take a stab at coding up what you want and then asking for help. Right  now it is difficult to tell what you want to  do or what your skill level is.

Answer (score 0):

`Function` has a specific meaning in `VBA`: it is called from either a cell (as in *User Defined Function*) or from other code, and returns a value to the caller.  Sounds like what you want is a `Sub` assigned to a keyboard shortcut.

Once your `Sub` is called, the question becomes how to determine what `Array` (I think you means a `Range` of `Cells` here) to work on.  This can be determined in many ways, including

- Hard coded range references
- Work on the active `Selection` object
- Prompt the user (possibly via a `Form`) to *enter* or *select* a range

Wrapping all this into a `Add-In` is quite simple, depending on you programming knowledge.  As others have commented, it is best to give it a go, and ask specific questions, with details of what you have tried, when you get stuck.

A good reference to get started is [Chip Pearson's Site](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx)